# Java Applet not Working With HTML

Tags: java, html, css, applet

I made an Applet. This applet works in appletviewer perfectly. But, when I put this applet's class file in a directory along with it's Jar File in which I have signed myself, and create an .HTML File with the applet tags it doesn't work. I keep getting `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied`.
How can I make this work? here is the source code, below it is the problem, and below that is how the applet is embedded.:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.applet.AppletStub;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RSLoad extends JApplet implements AppletStub {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final HashMap<String, String> PARAMETERS = new HashMap<String, String>();
private static final String LINK = "http://world2.runescape.com/";

public void init() {
    try {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(775, 540);
        parse(LINK);
        dwnld(LINK + PARAMETERS.get("archive"));
        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("Runescape.jar").toURI().toURL()});
        Class<?> client = loader.loadClass("Rs2Applet");
        Applet applet = (Applet) client.newInstance();
        applet.setStub(this);
        applet.init();
        applet.start();
        add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void appletResize(int width, int height) {
}

public final String getParameter(String name) {
    return PARAMETERS.get(name);
}
public final URL getDocumentBase() {
    try {
        return new URL(LINK);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public final URL getCodeBase() {
    try {
        return new URL(LINK);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public final AppletContext getAppletContext() {
    return null;
}

private void parse(final String url) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("app") && line.contains("write")) {
                PARAMETERS.put("<app", "");
                PARAMETERS.put("let ", "");
            } else if (line.contains("scriptsrc") || line.contains("ie6")) {
            } else if (line.contains("document.write")) {
                line = line.replaceAll("document.write", "").replaceAll("<param name=\"", "").replaceAll("\">'", "\"").replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(";", "").replaceAll("value", "");
                String[] splitted = line.split("=");
                if (splitted.length == 1) {
                    PARAMETERS.put(splitted[0], "");
                } else if (splitted.length == 2) {
                    PARAMETERS.put(splitted[0], splitted[1]);
                } else if (splitted.length == 3) {
                    PARAMETERS.put(splitted[0], splitted[1] + splitted[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Parsing!");
    }
}

private void dwnld(final String url) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Runescape.jar");
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int x;
        while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            out.write(data, 0, x);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Downloading!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

```
'java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission world2.runescape.com:80 connect,resolve)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Applet2SecurityManager.java:505)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:528)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at RSLoad.dwnld(RSLoad.java:95)
at RSLoad.init(RSLoad.java:26)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1639)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:667)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:118)
at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(File.java:501)
at java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile(File.java:517)
at java.io.File.toURI(File.java:660)
at RSLoad.init(RSLoad.java:27)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1639)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Embedded like this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <applet code=RSLoad.class archive="RSLoad.jar" width=100% height=100%>
 </applet>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you prompted to accept the digitally signed code?  BTW - Why code an applet rather than a frame?

Comment: I am prompted to accept the code and I'm doing an applet for a special project.

Comment: *"I am prompted to sign the code"*  I asked if you were prompted to ***accept*** the signed code.  *"I'm doing an applet for a special project."*  That does not answer my question.  Why an applet rather than a frame?  What is it about this special project requires an applet (specifically)?

Comment: Well its for a special project but another reason would be so that other people could access it at will because The new Runescape Applet lags alot and I get better FPS in an Applet/JFrame. But the reason its not in a frame because not many people want to download something and I thought it would be best if they went to a website instead.

Comment: BTW - just noticed `implements AppletStub`.  What are you trying to achieve by that?  I have written hundreds of applets and worked on thousands, yet the number of times I've had to ***implement*** an `AppletStub` amounts to (counting..) **1**.  That was for [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/), which is a desktop app. for loading& testing applets.  What use-case do ***you*** have for implementing an `AppletStub`?  (And be specific, none of this 'special project' waste of my time.)

Comment: *"best if they went to a website instead."* Java Web Start is designed to launch `JFrame` based apps. from a link on a web page.  *"not many people want to download something"*  Fewer people are willing to accept signed code, especially if it uses a non-verified code signing certificate.  If the user is willing to accept signed code, they will not only accept (but indeed prefer) a free-floating GUI.

Comment: Also just notice `setSize(775, 540);`  Don't do that in an applet.  An applet's size is set by the HTML (or JavaScript).  An applet should not be adjusting it's own size once called.

Comment: I won't give information on the special project. And implementing AppletStub is needed or else the parsing and downloading won't work. And the people who are going to be using this have no and when I say no I mean not a bit of knowledge of about java. Many of them think they'll be getting a virus by downloading something and they don't know what applets are so it saves me trouble.

Comment: (I have to point out, that if you have two of these applets in the same AppContext, they'll trash each other's `PARAMETERS` object.)

Comment: (Oh, and after a bit more of a look (which I don't usually do), I see you are running unsigned code in a non-secure manner and also reading there seems to be something about reading from URLs specified in another unsigned source.)

Comment: I am running it from signed code -.-

Answer (score 0):

Either your certificate is not trusted in the browser, or the user hasn't given explicit permission. You've given us the code (definately a good thing), but nothing about the signature itself, the browser or the way you've embedded the applet.

Comment: I'll add that stuff in a little bit please check back. Thanks for all the guys who are attempting to help me.